# MySql Query acts differently on my local version (8.0.21) and my staging (5.7.12)

Tags: mysql, subquery, version

I have an issue running a query on MySql using a Goapplication.

My local version works fine using mysql 8.0.21 but the same query on my staging version 5.7.12 on aurora fails

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT ? AS item_id, ? AS ar
    )
AS A
    JOIN item ON A.item_id = item.id
    AND A.ar + item.existing_qty > item.qty;
```

Running this code in data grip with replacements works fine on both local and staging
Running this code but replacing the question marks with ints works fine

The error I get is:

> Error 1054: Unknown column 'A.ar' in 'field list

I am thinking there is some driver / version issue

Comment: Perhaps "SELECT ?" isn't supported in 5.x

Comment: Maybe, seemed weird that it worked from an ide?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you phrase the query like this?

```
select count(*)
from item 
where item = ? and existing_qty + ? < qty
```

This is the same logic as your original query, and the parameters are passed in the same order.

Comment: Yes is does, but it does not really solve my issue, as I need multiple items in my subquery, I guess I could add lots of case statements